# Error ¨Sheduled backup delayed¨ even though network is available

Tags: 12.04, boot, backup

I get this message every time I bootup the machine

```
Schedule Backup delayed
Backup will begin when a network connection becomes available
```

The network is working fine and I can use the internet, also I can manually perform backups. I am a new user & using ubuntu 12.04 precise pangolin. Below is the link of screenshot of the error message(Unable to attach image as a new user).

Here is the error message:

[image]

Comment: There is a bug reported about this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/deja-dup/+bug/982316

Comment: Also happens in 14.04

Comment: Still happening in 2022!